# Use Monit monitor a python program

Tags: monit

I'm using Monit to monitor a system. I have a python file I wish to also monitor, I understand that I need to create a wrapper script as python does not generate pid files. I followed the instructions on this [site](http://markhildreth.me/article/monit-without-pidfiles/), however I have been unable to get the script to start. I've never created a wrapper script before, so I think I have an error in my script.  The log from monit says "Failed to start"

Monit rule

```
check process scraper with pidfile /var/run/scraper.pid
   start = "/bin/scraper start"
   stop = "/bin/scraper stop"
```

wrapper script

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE=/var/run/scraper.pid

case $1 in
   start)
      echo $$ > ${PIDFILE};
      source /home
      exec python /home/scraper.py 2>/dev/null
   ;;
   stop)
      kill `cat ${PIDFILE}` ;;
   *)
      echo "usage: scraper {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Using exec will replace the shell by the `exec`'d program, this is not what you want to get here, you want your wrapper script to launch the program and detach it before returning, writing its PID to a file so it can be stopped later.

Here's a fixed version:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE=/var/run/scraper.pid

case $1 in
   start)
       source /home
       # Launch your program as a detached process
       python /home/scraper.py 2>/dev/null &
       # Get its PID and store it
       echo $! > ${PIDFILE} 
   ;;
   stop)
      kill `cat ${PIDFILE}`
      # Now that it's killed, don't forget to remove the PID file
      rm ${PIDFILE}
   ;;
   *)
      echo "usage: scraper {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: I don't really follow why source is used, since the link in the question now goes to a 404. Could this be commented? Also, what are the two files called and where are they located? Thanks :)

Comment: I think this will stop the script

Answer (score 2):

You could also bypass the whole wrapper thing entirely by adding a small function that writes the pidfile inside your script. Something such as:

```
import os

def writePidFile():
    pid = str(os.getpid())
    currentFile = open(‘/var/run/myPIDFile.pid’, ‘w’)
    currentFile.write(pid)
    currentFile.close()
```

I found myself using this method instead since it is a much more straight forward approach and it is self contained in the script.

Comment: How do you handle start/stop actions?

Comment: Follow the instructions from the tutorial website. The PID file is nothing more than the Process ID so that the program/script can be started/stopped. You still have to define those as per the instructions here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit